# Pass String array and indexes using Struct to a thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I am trying to pass a string array and indexes from where to start end searching in the array, I am unable to solve it from the last two days. I am sending to the pthread_create a struct data thread_data, here i am able to send the int and long data, but not the string array, can someone help me, how to pass these.

```
struct data{
        int  tid;
        unsigned long start;
        unsigned long end;
        char * word;
        char * str;
        };

struct data thread_data[NUM_THREADS];
void *searchString(void *passeddata)
{
   struct data *t_data;
   int tid1;
   char * str[3];
   t_data=(struct data *) passeddata;
   tid1=t_data->tid;
   str=t_data->str;
  .....
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}       
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
...
char  work[]={"First Line","Second line","Third line"};
...

   while(fgets(arr[index],120, fp)!=NULL){
        index=index+1;
        thread_data[index].tid=index;
        thread_data[index].str=work;
        ...
        rc=pthread_create(&threads[index],NULL,searchString,(void *)&thread_data[index]);
...     
        }

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: This line 
`char  work[]={"First Line","Second line","Third line"};` you need 2D array.

Comment: @kiranBiradar I have changed it, stil facing the issue. Am i doing it right with declaration in struct for the string array char * str; and passing the string array thread_data[index].str=work; to the pthread_create or do i have change that.

Comment: No t_data->str should be of type char *arr[3]

Comment: @kiranBiradar i have to compute the required size based upon the number of lines in the file. So, i dont have the size to add that size in the struct. Did u mean declaration in the struct as char * str[] ?

Comment: In that case use pointer to pointer and allocate the memory dynamically.

Comment: Check my below answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hold the multiple strings you need 2D array.

```
const char  *work[]={"First Line","Second line","Third line", "Fourth Line"};
```

You need to use pointer to pointer in `struct data` to hold the above array.

```
struct data{
        .....
        const char **str;
        size_t lenOfStr;
        };
```

And pass the length of array explicitly to thread function from `main` function.

Your sample code may look like below.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
struct data{
        int  tid;
        unsigned long start;
        unsigned long end;
        char * word;
        const char **str;
        size_t lenOfStr;
        };

struct data thread_data[3];

void *searchString(void *passeddata)
{
   struct data *t_data;
   int tid1;
   const char **str = NULL;
   t_data=(struct data *) passeddata;

   tid1=t_data->tid;
   str=t_data->str;

  int i = 0;
   for (i = 0;i<t_data->lenOfStr;i++)
   printf("%s\n", str[i]);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const char  *work[]={"First Line","Second line","Third line", "Fourth Line"};
        int index = 0;
        pthread_t threadid=0;

        thread_data[index].tid=index;
        thread_data[index].str=work;
        thread_data[index].lenOfStr = sizeof(work)/sizeof(*work); // Calculate the size of work here

        int rc=pthread_create(&threadid,NULL,searchString,&thread_data[index]);

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Those string literals are `const`, so it should be `char const*[]`. And no need to explicitly cast `void*` to another pointer because it is in implicit conversion in C.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Taken your suggestion!.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Yay!, It works. Beginner here didnt know about pointer to pointer. Thanks

Comment: @Roger Happy to help :)